# Doubt regarding lifts (and inertia?)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertia

so i was thinking about lifts and i am confused.
let's say there is a body within a lift (system at rest). Now if the lift starts to accelerate downwards with say an acceleration a ($a>g$). The body and the lift separate due to inertia and the body is now under an acceleration of $g$ (down)[as the body is under free fall]. So the separation b/w the body and the lift will keep on increasing as the relative acceleration b/w body and lift is $a-g$  (i.e relative to the body the lift moves away from it at a-g acceleration(correct me if i am mistaken).

now if the lift accelerates down with acceleration $a'$ (now $a'<g$). The body again must separate first due to its inertia but in this case the body has a greater acceleration $g$ compared to the lift.
So my question is for how long is the separation maintained (as in, what is the expression for that time period based on the given variables)?

(i am just a h.s student so i have an understanding of basic mechanics and kinematics, ig i am just overthinking or am just confused, please correct me if my thinking is wrong)

Comment: Tell us why you think the body will separate when a<g

Comment: i am actually not sure, maybe the object doesn't separate if the lift has smaller acceleration than itself?. I mean if something starts moving , shouldn't the objects inside which were at rest separate  because they were initially at rest so they will be resistant to move [ assuming this for a vertically moving system].( please correct my intuition if i am wrong).

Comment: Or, do objects only separate/ move from there position if the vehicle in which its travelling has a greater acceleration than the object?

Comment: i think i have understood, the body wont separate in the second case

Comment: You are right, the body would not separate, but it is easier to lift a weight. Same thing if you would be on the moon, g is much smaller but you do not separate, The new g' in the elevator going down with a<g would be g'=g-a